# Uniform continuity on a finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-continuity

Take a function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. For **any** given $\alpha > 0$, I would like to be able to find a $\beta > 0 $ such that $$ \forall x, x' \in \mathbb{R} : \ |x - x'| \leq \beta \implies |f(x) - f(x')| \leq \alpha.$$
If I am not wrong, this is an implication of *uniform convergence*.

Now I would like to modify this. Fix a number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrarily. For **any** given $\alpha > 0$, we would like to be able to find a $\beta>0$ such that $$ \forall x, x' \in [-r, r] : \ |x - x'| \leq \beta \implies |f(x) - f(x')| \leq \alpha.$$

So I would like to claim something similar to the uniform convergence but on a bounded interval. I think the latter one is less restrictive as, e.g., $f(x) = x^2$ satisfies the latter property but it is not uniformly continuous.

My question is: do we have a name for this version of uniform convergence?

Comment: That is just asserting that the restriction of $f$ to $[-r,r]$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It's called continuous.  Any function that's continuous on a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is necessarily uniformly continuous on that subset.

Comment: Thanks! It is apparently due to Heine-Cantor theorem: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_on_Closed_Real_Interval_is_Uniformly_Continuous